# Not in scope: `S.elementOf'

Tags: haskell

why load a normal file, have error Not in scope: `S.elementOf'

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Error
import qualified Data.Set as S

....
freshen s = do
        names <- get
        let s' = head [ns|suf<-suffixes
              ,let ns = s ++ show suf
              ,not (ns `S.elementOf` names)]
        suffixes = [1..]
        put (S.insert s' names)
        return s'
```

Answer (score 5):

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Set.html shows no `elementOf` function, it has a `member` function, though.

Answer (score 2):

The function you want is called `member`. If you want to negate it, there is also a function `notMember`.